# Servicenow Rest API link broken after Upgrade to San Diego

Tags: rest, servicenow, servicenow-rest-api

I am pulling a report on sc_req_item table, this is the command:

curl --user username:password https://myurl.service-now.com/api/now/table/sc_req_item?sysparm_display_value=true&sysparm_exclude_reference_link=true&sysparm_limit=1

I am getting this error:

{"error":{"detail":"NullPointerException Check logs for error trace or enable glide.rest.debug property to verify REST request processing","message":"NullPointerException"},"status":"failure"}'

It was working fine before the upgrade to latest release(san diego).
and also QA and DEV are returning results, only issue is with PROD.

Could you guys please help.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the system log? The most likely culprits are a function field, a  calculated field, or a before query business rule.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the `sc_req_item` table in Production corresponds to the versions available in your QA and DEV environments.

You could also test the request in production without the `sysparm_display_value` set to true.